# No up-votes to my posts?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I am currently banned from asking any questions on Stack Overflow. I have tried editing my posts, but I seem to be getting no up-votes, probably because of lack of views. Is there anyway to get more up-votes or getting unbanned?

Comment: Why did you add half answers to your own questions?

Comment: Which questions specifically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758975/infinite-looping-in-a-qt-widget-project

Comment: Whoa, from less than 10 points and several -3 questions to over 80 points in one day....

Comment: I know, talk about a miracle. Thanks to anyone who upvoted!

Comment: You're asking C++ questions.  C++ developers are a crusty, angry bunch, stingy with their praise and generous with their ire.  It must be tough as hell being a new user in that tag.  Not sure what there is to do about it, however.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try answering questions.

If that's not an option, make more edits to your questions - make sure they are significant and that they add as much information as possible, and follows the suggestions on [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: If I do edit my posts, do others even see the updates?

Comment: Edits do bump the post to the front page. However, if you make _many_, _insignificant_ edits, this may get noticed and may be seen as abuse.

Comment: Thanks, I will do my best to make the information more valuable!

Comment: @Oded: Do you know why all questions of ZERO have a -3 ? I find it a bit odd because while the questions are not outstanding, they are also not bad. Looks a bit like serial downvoting.

Comment: @ThorstenS. - The edit history shows that the questions were badly formatted to begin with. That is probably the source of the downvotes.

Comment: @Oded: Ok, that may happen. Despite the insistence that valid answers will be upvoted over time, it happens that some answer or questions have no activity at all and will not regenerate even after polishing it...

Comment: Actually posting answers doesn't factor into the question ban (or vise vera) if I recall correctly. The ban is based on question score.

Comment: @BenBrocka Nope, answers count.